# Why dll doesn't run if VS2010 doesn't exist?

Tags: java, visual-studio-2010, dll, jna

l've written a dll on VS2010 and I will call it from JAVA by the help of JNA.But it doesn't run if VS 2010 doesn't exist on computer.It gives errors

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   Unable to load library 'C:\Users\hasan\Desktop\cv-2dll.dll': The
>   specified module could not be found.  at
>   com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:166)     at
>   com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:239)     at
>   com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.(Library.java:140)  at
>   com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:393)   at
>   com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:378)   at
>   hsv.HSVHistogram.main(HSVHistogram.java:24)   at
>   hsv.HSVView.jButton1ActionPerformed(HSVView.java:231)     at
>   hsv.HSVView.access$900(HSVView.java:25)   at
>   hsv.HSVView$5.actionPerformed(HSVView.java:134)   at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6288)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6053)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4651)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:643)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
>     at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:616)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:614)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:613)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)

Comment: Are you sure that its not the .Net 4 Framework that is missing?

Comment: Seriously?  `'C:\Users\hasan\Desktop\cv-2dll.dll': The specified module could not be found.`

Comment: use the dependency walker to find which module is missing

Answer (score 0):

Your DLL probably needs the C/C++ runtime DLLs.  The computer without Visual Studio 2010 installed probably doesn't have them.

Try compiling your DLL so that the C/C++ Runtime Library is statically linked into the DLL.  Open the properties page for your DLL project in VS 2010, then select the Configuration Properties->C/C++->Code Generation subdialog and select Multi-threaded (/MT) or Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd).  Once you recompile & relink the DLL it should run on systems without the VS 2010 runtime DLLs.

Comment: I did as you said dll's size increased bu it still gives the same error when I call it from java.Is there any other way of solving this problem?

Comment: THen I recommend going to [www.dependencywalker.com](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) & downloading the dependency walker program to determine which other DLLs your DLL needs.